# PowerBuilder how to create catalog tables

Tags: powerbuilder

I am starting to use PowerBuilder on a new Microsoft SQL Server 2000 r2.
I know that I should create catalog tables in the database like pbcatcol etc, but I have not been able to find a script to do that.
It is not installed in the PowerBuilder directory tree, it should be a .sql file, and probably a different version for every supported database.
Where can I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terry has right. It happened to me, that we used a different schema than dbo, and we need to set the schema here: Database Profile Setup/System tabpage/Powerbuilder Catalog Table Owner

If it was not set, PB could not create these tables.

Br. Gábor

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this will happen for you automagically from the IDE; it will create the catalog tables for you. I'm not certain if it's the first time you connect to the database, or the first time you open the DataWindow painter or save from the DataWindow painter, but they end up there on their own (after you've supplied the connection parameters, of course).

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: I believe that it happens the first time you connect to the database. Unless you've turned off that option.

Comment: This is correct. You need to log in with system priviliges (at least in Oracle) the first time. We used to have the DBA come to our desk and log in so the tables would get created. Otherwise get the DDL and run it.